# Are there any Christian denominations that consider LDS (Mormons) to be Christians?

Tags: lds, denomination-survey

A [recent Pew poll](https://www.pewforum.org/2011/11/23/romneys-mormon-faith-views-of-the-mormon-religion/) of Americans found that a majority of Christians consider Mormons to be Christian, with 51% saying 'yes' compared to only 31% saying 'no'. So, of those having an opinion, 62% say Mormons are Christians.

However, this seems to be at odds with official views toward the LDS church among Christian denominations. The article *[Are Mormons Christian? It's complicated](https://www.christiancentury.org/article/2012-01/are-mormons-christian-its-complicated)* says

> "Evangelicals [...] tend to be the most eager to keep Mormons from the
> Christian camp. [...] But even Catholics and more liberal Protestants,
> such as the Presbyterian Church (USA), the Evangelical Lutheran Church
> in America and the United Methodist Church, do not consider Mormon
> baptisms valid."

Are there any denominations in the 'core' Christian branches of Catholicism, Orthodoxy, and Protestantism that recognize the LDS church as Christian?

Comment: I've read that article and it is interesting to note that they use the phrase `do not consider Mormon baptisms valid` instead of not Christian. Is it valid baptism that makes one Christian (If so who/what denotes validity)? related [question](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/24193/22319) and [this one](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/24217/what-is-the-basis-that-many-mainstream-christian-groups-justify-labeling-groups)

Comment: Interestingly enough, I was going to ask this exact question some while ago, and had already looked into the matter. AFAICT, the short answer is "no". I'll post the various official positions I found as a proper answer.

Comment: Considering there's a good chance that the majority of people in the US who self identify as Christian aren't, I wouldn't put much weight on that poll. (Why identify as Christian? Because in the US it's currently a net benefit.)

Comment: @Joshua If you have a poll from 'active' or 'devout' Christians, I'm interested.

Comment: Considering the difficulty of constructing the poll (even from the results given in that poll, only half the participants are qualified to speak, and most likely that's an overstatement) I don't see much point in attempting it.

Comment: This seems more like an issue of context-subjectivity rather than factual-disagreement because most folks would probably consider Mormons to be "_Christian_" in some broader contexts but not in other more specific contexts.

Comment: reminds me of [meta question](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/a/104/22319)

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because on-topic help center says: `there are questions that are not constructive for the format of this site. These include questions asking for: whether some group or person is "Christian"`

Comment: @depperm That is talking about questions of the form "Do you think person X/group Y is really Christian?" Those questions are questions of opinion and not allowed. But questions of the form "Does group A think group B are really Christian?" are, in theory, objectively answerable, and have always been on-topic here. A denomination survey question like this is also fine.

Answer (score 26):

The *official positions* of at least several major denominations do indeed hold that the theology of Latter Day Saints is not Christian:

#### RCC

> the Mormons are not to be considered as belonging to an "ecclesial community not in full communion with the Catholic Church" [...] if a Mormon wishes to become Catholic, the norms that regulate admission to the Church of non-Catholic Christians cannot be applied. [...] Mormons are to be considered non-baptized ([Source](https://www.vatican.va/roman_curia/congregations/cfaith/documents/rc_con_cfaith_doc_20010605_battesimo_mormoni-navarrete_en.html); see also [this](https://www.vatican.va/roman_curia/congregations/cfaith/documents/rc_con_cfaith_doc_20010605_battesimo_mormoni-ladaria_en.html))

#### LCMS

> The Lutheran Church—Missouri Synod, together with the vast majority of Christian denominations in the United States, does not regard the Mormon church as a Christian church.
> ([Source](https://www.lcms.org/about/beliefs/faqs/denominations#mormon))

#### WELS

> Mormonism cannot be considered a Christian denomination. ([Source](https://wels.net/faq/lutherans-and-mormons/))

#### ELCA

I could not find a direct statement, however, a publication on baptism and Mormonism had this to say:

> [Mormon] teaching about the nature of God is substantially different from that of orthodox, creedal Christianity. Because the Mormon understanding of the Word of God is not the same as the Christian understanding, it is correct to say that Christian Baptism has not taken place. ([Source](https://download.elca.org/ELCA%20Resource%20Repository/Do_Lutherans_rebaptize_former_Mormons_who_are_joining_the_congregation.pdf))

[This question](/questions/52365) also asks about ELCA specifically. The top answer cites the same document.

#### UMC

> The United Methodist Church recognizes the baptism of other Christian denominations [...] The Church of Jesus Christ of Latter Day Saints [...] is not what we consider Christian baptism. ([Source](https://www.umc.org/en/content/ask-the-umc-does-the-united-methodist-church-accept-the-baptism-of-other-denominations))

#### GOAoA

The GOAoA's official stance is in line with that of the other churches already mentioned, but is expressed much less charitably. Accordingly, I decline to quote it. [Read at your own risk](https://www.goarch.org/-/cults-in-america). See also [this](https://www.goarch.org/introduction-articles/-/asset_publisher/zg5D5ENaCTK9/content/why-non-orthodox-are-excluded-from-the-sacrament-of-holy-communion), [this](https://www.goarch.org/-/sunday-of-orthodoxy) and [this](https://www.goarch.org/-/the-stand-of-the-orthodox-church-on-controversial-issues), with the same disclaimer.

#### Presbyterians

> Mormonism is a new religious tradition distinct from the historic, apostolic tradition of the Church ([source](https://www.presbyterianmission.org/wp-content/uploads/presbyteriansandlatterdaysaints.pdf) — not searchable, quote is from p2¶1)

#### Anglican / Episcopalian (Church of England)

I was unable to find any official statement, however I did find a document that had this to say:

> The Anglican Church, the Episcopal Church [...] sees in the Book of Mormon a most interesting document, **but not the Word of God**. It is probably the first large-scale piece of American fiction. ([Source](http://anglicanhistory.org/canada/rfpalmer/mormons.html); emphasis in original)

While the document does not seem (note that I only skimmed it) to explicitly call LDS non-Christian, it does assert that TBoM is in no way scriptural or spiritually useful and calls Mormonism a "new religion" which it contrasts with Christianity.

Additionally, a careful reading of [this document](https://livingchurch.org/covenant/2015/05/28/let-episcopal-mormon-dialogue-begin/), while not containing a direct statement, strongly implies that the A/E church does not consider LDS to be Christian. (The gist of the article — again, I only skimmed it — appears to be a complaint that the A/E church is more willing to engage with Jews and Muslims than with Mormons.)

---

While I have not found official statements, AFAICT the Church of England (see A/E, above) and Southern Baptist Church feel similarly. Pentecostals (at least the AoG) seem to share the GOAoA's stance, although I again could not locate any official statement. There may be other churches for which I tried and failed to find any explicit statement; this answer is substantially drawn from notes I recorded previously, and I did not record failures at the time.

Nevertheless, those churches that *do* have official statements on this question would seems to cover a fairly broad spectrum of other Christian churches. (Feel free to ask if you'd like me to specifically research any others. Beware, however, that it is difficult to find official statements from some of the more loosely organized churches.)

Please note these *are not my personal opinions* nor (as per the question) the opinions of random *members* of these churches, but are (as best I can determine) *official* opinions of various denominations generally accepted to be "Christian". In particular, I have tried to limit sources to official publications where possible.

Something else to keep in mind is that we are not generally discussing whether or not *individuals* are Christian, but whether a particular church considers the *doctrine* of LDS to be Christian. Just as Lutherans might consider the RCC to be heretical while still asserting that there are "true Christians" in the RCC in spite of this, most (non-LDS) churches would say that there may well be "true Christians" that are nominally Mormon/LDS in spite of the non-Christian (according to them) doctrine of the LDS. That is, there is a significant difference between the statements "the LDS is not a Christian *church*" and "(all) Mormons are not Christians".

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/128326/discussion-on-answer-by-matthew-are-there-any-christian-denominations-that-consi).

Answer (score 5):

In recent years, there is more acceptance to acknowledge LDS as Christian, despite the fact that certain parts of the doctrine are different and the baptism is not accepted as valid.

In 2008, there was an ecumenical conference where they were invited among their fellow Christian ministers. [How the Mormons got an invitation to the Pope’s ecumenical meeting](https://bycommonconsent.com/2009/08/29/how-the-mormons-met-the-pope/):

> Massa relates some of the theological grounding for such an  arrangement: although Mormons are not sacramentally initiated  Christians (Mormon baptism is not a valid Christian baptism according  to the Vatican), “room must be made for those who seek salvation under  the mantle of Christ’s saving cross, even while denying other  essential elements of the Christian faith.”

Comment: This refers to those 'seeking' salvation, who 'deny ... essential elements of the Christian faith'.

Comment: @NigelJ And by that he means mormons, so what is the comment for?

Comment: Those who are 'seeking salvation' and who 'deny the essential elements of Christianity' could not be (properly) classified as 'Christian'. Denying the essential elements of any ideology surely places one outside of that ideology, not inside it.

Comment: @NigelJ In any case, here LDS were grouped with the other christian denominations instead of "other religions".

Comment: @kutschkem Might that be due to the name of the church - The Church of Jesus Christ of Latter-day Saints - that accommodation?

Comment: @KorvinStarmast that name has been there for over hundred years, yet here we are discussing whether The Church of Jesus Christ of Latter-Day Saints is a Christian church. The thought process is in the blog post, the name is irrelevant. LDS identify as Christian, period. Whether others grant them this identity is the topic of the question.